# Mastrad Orka pancake spatula

Tags: equipment, pancakes

Where can I purchase the 
Mastrad Orka pancake spatula?  It has a curved silicone blade about 8" long and 1" to 1 1/2" wide with a nice silicone handle. Some websites indicate this item is discontinued. Does anyone know why that might be?

Comment: You could rephrase that question as "Is there a reason for the XYZ megaspatula to be discontinued, and that a cook has to care about, for example that item being defective, unsafe or unreliable?" ... otherwise, there is a risk of the "shopping" or "too-localized" off-topic criteria matching it.

Answer (score 1):

Search google for this term and you'll find lots of suppliers.

ob210101

Buy several so you have a supply if and when they finally run out.